# paintComponent on JPanel not working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I've spent almost 2 hours now on it but I can't get it working.
I just want to paint a image on a **JPanel**.

I want to paint the `imageChaser` image on the arena JPanel.
But it's not displaying.
What am i doing wrong?

Heres my code :

```
public class GuiGameBoard extends JPanel {

//import stuff


private JPanel arena;

BufferedImage imageChaser;
BufferedImage imageChaserSelected;
BufferedImage imageTarget;

public GuiGameBoard() {

    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    arena = new JPanel();
    arena.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    arena.setBackground(Color.BLACK);


    this.add(arena);

    try 
    {
        File inputChaser = new File("resources\\chaser.png");
        imageChaser = ImageIO.read(inputChaser);

        File inputChaserSelected = new File("resources\\chaser_selected.png");
        imageChaserSelected = ImageIO.read(inputChaserSelected);

        File inputTarget = new File("resources\\target.png");
        imageTarget = ImageIO.read(inputTarget);

    } 
    catch (IOException ie) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error:"+ie.getMessage());
    }

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(imageChaser, 0, 0, null);
}

}
```

Comment: SO is not for code review or debugging. Describe your exact problem, post the smallest possible code to show the problem and ask again.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  It is quite possible the problem is in code not shown. 2) `new File("resources\\target.png");`  By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`. 3) `g.drawImage(imageChaser, 0, 0, null);` should be `g.drawImage(imageChaser, 0, 0, this);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is, that your hiding your picture by adding the `JPanel arena` to your GuiGameBoard class, which already is a JPanel.

But without an SSCCE, giving an adequate answer isn't possible...

Comment: +1, you add a Black panel which is 500 x 500 on top of the image. So unless the image is bigger than that you won't see any of the image.

Comment: How can i make that the image overrides the 500x500 black panel? Because the black panel is the "Arena" and the images are battleships.

Comment: Use a normal panel with a black background. Then you create JLabels with an ImageIcon and add the labels to your panel.

Comment: I would do that, but the problem is that below the "arena" is another JPanel with some buttons such as pause. So i need to use 2 JPanels below eachother, and on the "Arena" JPanel i want to paint the images.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget a 'top-level container' e.g. JFrame.

Take a look at this example
[example code](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/DrawImage.htm).

For more information [click here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/)

Comment: I can see the panel's background, but the icon is not showing. The JFrame is in an other class.